# Calling VS12 std::transform?

Tags: c++, c++11

After an upgrade of a project to Visual Studio 2012 I encountered a problem with a call to std::transform. Because it is part of a large codebase, I simplified the code below:

```
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Real>
std::vector<std::complex<Real>> createVector(int n) {
    std::vector<std::complex<Real>> filter(n);
    std::transform(filter.begin()+1, filter.begin()+(n-1)/2+1, filter.rbegin(), std::conj<Real>);
}

int main() {
    createVector<double>(10);
}
```

When compiling I get multiple errors (little bit shortened, all for the same code line):

```
Error   1   error C2780: '_OutTy *std::transform(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InTy (&)[_InSize],_OutTy (&)[_OutSize],_Fn2)' : expects 5 arguments - 4 provided
Error   2   error C2780: '_OutTy *std::transform(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_OutTy (&)[_OutSize],_Fn2)' : expects 5 arguments - 4 provided
Error   3   error C2780: '_OutIt std::transform(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InTy (&)[_InSize],_OutIt,_Fn2)' : expects 5 arguments - 4 provided
Error   4   error C2780: '_OutIt std::transform(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_OutIt,_Fn2)' : expects 5 arguments - 4 provided   
Error   5   error C2784: '_OutTy *std::transform(_InIt,_InIt,_OutTy (&)[_OutSize],_Fn1)' : could not deduce template argument for '_OutTy (&)[_OutSize]'
Error   6   error C2914: 'std::transform' : cannot deduce template argument as function
Error   7   error C2784: '_OutIt std::transform(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,_Fn1)' : could not deduce template argument for '_OutIt' from 'std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt>'
```

I think std::transform performs some template recursive creation because of the multiple errors for one call. I also tried setting the template parameter explicity, but with no success. There are six overloads of std::transform and somehow I think it is trying to match with the `size` parameters. I'm simply trying to match the simplest overload in `algorithm` of VS12:

```
template<class _InIt, class _OutIt, class _Fn1> inline 
_OutIt transform(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _OutIt _Dest, _Fn1 _Func){...}
```

Any help?

Thanks,
Erwin

Comment: The error message shows the overload candidates considered. The surprise is the last overload, which is in fact correct, and rejected because of `filter.rbegin()` ! The answers which focus on `std::conj` don't actually address this (probably work by coincidence). This appears to be a Visual C++ bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual c++ 2012 uses C++11 and `std::conj` is overloaded in that case.
use `static_cast` to select the right function. I personally prefer a lambda:

```
std::transform(x, y, z, [](std::complex<Real> const& x){return std::conj(x);});
```

Comment: OP is passing `std::conj<Real>`, which is `std::conj<double>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `static_cast`. You can use a predicate this way:

```
struct A {
    complex<double> operator()( complex<double> i) const {return conj<double>(i);}  
};

template <typename Real>
std::vector<std::complex<Real>> createVector(int n) {
    std::vector<std::complex<Real>> filter(n);
    std::transform( filter.begin(), filter.end(), filter.rbegin(), A());
    return filter;
}
```

[compiled example](http://ideone.com/5GaOeF)

In C++11 with lambda:

```
std::transform( filter.begin(), filter.end(), filter.rbegin(), 
                     [](std::complex<Real> const& x){return std::conj(x);});
```